# Issue with JDBC connection pool in web application

Tags: java, jdbc

I am facing an issue with connection pool. using tomcat8,primefaces 5.1 and Eclipse. when I test my code with single user it is working fine but when I use with 2 users, when accessing user2 while user1 is in progress user1 is getting stuck and user2 is started processing. when user2 finished processing both users are coming out at same time and user1 is not displaying any output(user2 is getting partial data) and getting exhausted resultset error on both users. here is my code for connection pooling.

```
public GetConnection(){
    try {
        Context initContext = new InitialContext();
        Context envContext = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
        dataSource1 = (DataSource) envContext.lookup("jdbc/DB1");
        dataSource2 = (DataSource) envContext.lookup("jdbc/DB2");
        dataSource3 = (DataSource) envContext.lookup("jdbc/DB3");

    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

getting connection based on condition,

```
public Connection getConnections(int i) {

    try {
            if (i == 0) {
            connection = dataSource1.getConnection();
           } else if (i == 1) {
            connection = dataSource2.getConnection();
        } else {
            connection = dataSource3.getConnection();
       }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        addErrorMessage(ex.getMessage());
    }
    return connection;
}
```

I have to run 4 queries, for this I am creating connection and statement only once but have 4 resultsets, closing all these connections in finally block

```
 finally{
        if (rs != null) try { rs.close(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
         if (rs1 != null) try { rs1.close(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
         if (rs2 != null) try { rs2.close(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
         if (rs3 != null) try { rs3.close(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
         if (stmt != null) try { stmt.close(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
         if (connection != null) try { connection.close(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}

    }
```

can anyone please help me out in this?? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I got solution for this issue, i was using static for connection and other variables removing that resolved the issue. Thanks